# How can I convert from a Byte Array to Generic Array?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, bitconverter

**Disclaimer** - Since I have a working solution, this question perhaps crosses the line to code review, however I'm convinced I'm reinventing the wheel and a better solution exists.

### Context

I am working with a low level communication protocol whereby I receive a `byte[]` as a serialized array of a known type. The data type will always be an `unmanaged` value type, typically `UInt16`, `char` etc.

### Question

How can I (should I) generically convert from a `byte[]` to a `T[]` so as not to provide implementation for each case, or type specific converters?

### Working Code

I have written an Extension Method, `ToArray<T>`, on `byte[]`:

```cs
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this byte[] input)
    where T: unmanaged
{
    // Use Reflection to find the appropiate MethodInfo from BitConverter
    var converterMethod =  (from method in typeof(BitConverter).GetMethods()
                            // Double redundant selection
                            where ((method.ReturnType == typeof(T)) && (method.Name == $"To{typeof(T).Name}"))
                            select method).FirstOrDefault();
            
    // Create a Function delegate from the MethodInfo, since all BitConverter.To methods share a signiture
    var converter = converterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<byte[], int, T>));

    // Some meta variables regarding the target type
    int typeSize = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
    int count = input.Length / typeSize;
            
    // Error Checking - Not yet implmented
    if (input.Length % typeSize != 0) throw new Exception();
            
    // Resulting array generation
    T[] result = new T[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (T)converter.DynamicInvoke(
            input.Slice(i * typeSize, typeSize), 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This also depends on another small extension, `Slice<T>`, on `T[]`:

```cs
public static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] array, int index, int count)
{
    T[] result = new T[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) result[i] = array[index + i];
    return result;
}
```

### Test Case

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] test = new byte[6]
        {
            0b_0001_0000, 0b_0010_0111, // 10,000 in Little Endian
            0b_0010_0000, 0b_0100_1110, // 20,000 in Little Endian
            0b_0011_0000, 0b_0111_0101, // 30,000 in Little Endian
        };

        UInt16[] results = test.ToArray<UInt16>();

        foreach (UInt16 result in results) Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
10000
20000
30000
```

Comment: Do you actually need an array? You could do this with spans in 2 lines, and requires zero allocation/copy - you can coerce between blittable span types. Memory (span source) takes a *little* more work, but not much.

Comment: @MarcGravell Hello and thank you. I hadn't encountered spans before, looking briefly now I see how they replace my `Slice` extension. I'm afraid I don't see however how they would provide the generic conversion?

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, if this was me: I wouldn't get it as an array - I'd simply coerce between spans. An array is implicitly convertible to a span, so the input doesn't change. Span as an output is a *different* API, but very comparable in all ways except one (storage as a field).

Consider

```cs
public static Span<T> Coerce<T>(this byte[] input)
    where T: unmanaged
    => MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, T>(input);
```

This is zero allocation and zero processing - it simply reinterprets the span over the existing data, which means it is fundamentally doing exactly what `BitConverter` does behind the scenes. There's also the concept of `ReadOnlySpan<T>` if the consumer needs to read but doesn't need to be able to write to the data. And spans allow you to work on *portions* of an array without needing to convey the bounds separately.

And if you can't use spans as the return, you can still use this approach for the code:

```cs
public static T[] Convert<T>(this byte[] input)
    where T: unmanaged
    => MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, T>(input).ToArray();
```

Comment: That looks beautifully elegant, thank you! Really great stuff!

Comment: @george (context: your question about arrays, now edited out) well, I added an extra bit at the bottom that might be what you want, but that is then an additional allocation / copy. That's the trade off if you want an array. You *can* create a custom `MemoryManager<T>` to do this with zero copy, but that is more work - possibly 20 lines.

Comment: Thank you again, if I had more than one upvote to give, you'd get it!